# Create a hash index results in error #1071 on Aria

Tags: indexing, mariadb

I get an #1071 error on an [Aria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aria_(storage_engine)) table with this:

```
ALTER TABLE `code`
ADD UNIQUE `ix_code_url_sha` (`url_sha`(64)) USING HASH;
```

The column is a sha() of a URL column.

How do I create a unique hash index on an Aria-based SHA-1 column?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a [generated column](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/) and an index on it.

So from:

```
create table code (url varchar(160))
```

create the generated column and index:

```
alter table code add url_sha varbinary(32) as (unhex(sha2(url,256))) stored unique
```

Comment: I  was able to create the stored virtual column with this code on MariaDB 10.3. Awesome!  Interestingly it was stored as BTree. In my c101 knowledge it would make more sense to hash it. But there we are.